# Python: Replace a function member of an instance of a class

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have the following class (which is a PyTorch model in this example, but the question applies to any class in Python):

```py
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
```

Suppose I have an instance `model = MyModel()`. What I want to do is to modify the `forward` function of the instance `model` so that before doing the forward, it first does some pre-processing on the input. For example, if we want to clone (or repeat) `x`, then we can define the new forward function as follows:

```py
def new_forward(self, x):
    # x has shape (batch_size, ..., d)
    # we clone it to obtain (2 * batch_size, ..., d)
    x = torch.stack([x, x])
    x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=0, end_dim=1)
    return self.forward(x)
```

More precisely, I want `model.forward(x)` to do `model.new_forward(x)`.

How can I achieve this without modifying the code of `MyModel`?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

**Update:** I want to apply the pre-processing to all PyTorch models and not just `MyModel`. More precisely, I am given a variable `model`, which is an instance of `torch.nn.Module` but its type can be any subclass of `torch.nn.Module` (e.g. `MyModel`).

Comment: Do you want to do this because `model = MyModel()` is embedded in a function in third-party code, so you can't control its instantiation? Otherwise why not just subclass `MyModel`?

Comment: @dROOOze Because I want to apply the pre-processing to all PyTorch models and not just `MyModel`. More precisely, I am given a variable `model`, which is an instance of `torch.nn.Module` but its type can be any subclass of `torch.nn.Module` (e.g. `MyModel`).

Comment: So, do the duplicates linked above solve your question? If not, how don't they?